Pyparsing - documentation?
The docs at ReadTheDocs used to be downloadable as PDFs, HTML zips, etc. Those options don't seem to exist anymore. Where can I get - preferably HTML zips - documentation for off-line use?
Or, instructions on how to generate them? I tried to follow some 'recipes' on the net, but the process hardly seems trivial.
In my case, I was looking for the lastest pyparsing docs. In the RTD documentation, this still seems a possibility, but has to be enabled by the doc owner.
I suspect this has been disabled for all docs on ReadTheDocs though, as I read a comment about heavy loads on the servers.

If its repo is public, you can build the docs as a PDF yourself.
